# How to install Windows on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I need to install windows (7-10) under linux. I found  a way to deploy wim-image, i have a problem with bootloader. I didn't find a way to boot from grub directly. I wanna try to copy bootmgr via dd.

So, can you suggest me any bootloader(or grub option) to boot directly windows?

Thanks.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: You could virtualize it with KVM

Comment: Altlinux. It's not about VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Windows on Linux, you could try creating a virtual Windows machine running in VMware Player.

Also if you want to run specific windows programs/executables, have a look into wine.

Comment: I want to install windows from linux, not vm.

Comment: In your question you said 'under linux' which is implying you want to run windows while linux is running. Do you mean you want to install windows on the same hard drive as linux and be able to boot whichever you choose? If so you should have said 'besides linux'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I want to make an autoinstaller to install(pxe) linux + windows without user interaction.